# When I test this python function in Codecademy, it is denied and the console log says, "'return' outside function". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

```
def double_list(x):
    x = [3, 5, 7]
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(x)
```

I am being told that "return" on line 5 is outside the function, but when I indent to include it in the function the console log says I had an unexpected indentation.

Comment: Maybe you are indenting with tab characters where it expects spaces? If you are not sure you can just copy the white space before x in the second line and prepend it to your for loop..

Comment: The indentation is off, not recoverable, the original code y OP was just a one-liner. Indentation could be off somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation for your for loop is wrong, causing the return to be outside the function. Also it looks like you should be defining x outside the function:

```
def double_list(x):
    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

x = [3, 5, 7]
print double_list(x)
```

One extra change here is if you're using Python 2.x (inferred by your print statement), you should use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Answer (score 0):

your function has poor indentation. for loop should come inside of the definition.

```
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
x = [3, 5, 7]
print double_list(x)
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. the return should not be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the indentation is wrong, but also the way you call the function double_list(x). You need to define x before calling the function, or either define it inside the parenthesis. If what you need is a function that doubles the values of x (in order to have [6, 10, 14] in your example) this two options work well:

```
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
       x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
x=[3,5,7]
print (double_list(x))
```

---

```
 def double_list(x):
    x[:]=[x_el*2 for x_el in x]
    return x
x=[3,5,7]
print (double_list(x))
```